# mysql how to get constraint info based on hash key

Tags: mysql, sql

for example I have this error from mysql:

```
Duplicate entry 'abcccc0' for key 'UI_12avhpsjlui0u51pufmjebiyq'
```

By using what SQL query I can get more information about this key?

Thanks

Comment: wat is the table structure? try to check the table structure - show create table table_name/describe table_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> show create table `table_name`
>
> or
>
> describe `table_name`

for key info

> show keys in `table_name` where exprn

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Have patience .. OP will get back to u

Comment: thnx ..by the way :-)